# Exporting a bullet point in org-mode to theorem/defintion in latex

Tags: org-mode, latex

I'm two weeks old in Emacs and just short of one in org-mode, so not that much knowledge. I want to use org-mode to take my university and research notes. Some of those, are needed to be exported as LaTeX, say for an annual report. I know I can use

```
#+begin_definition
The Price of the Anarchy is defined as...
#+end_definition
```

to create a latex

```
\begin{definition}
The Price of the Anarchy is defined as...
\end{definition}
```

Cool. But this does not look good in org-mode. What I would love to do is something like this:

```
** Price of Anarchy                         :definition:
    The Price of the Anarchy is defined as...
```

And it would generate something close to the other case.

The same could be said about other environments, like proof, theorem, those more commonly used in maths and CS.

So, to sum it up: is there a way to place a tag like ":definition:" and transform the bullet point into that environment? And if not, can someone point how to make a script/hook (not sure what to call, again, emacs noob here) on how to do something like this?

Comment: I don't think so. You'd have to rewrite the LaTeX exporter to do that. The current one maps headlines into sectioning structures. There is no provision to turn them into arbitrary environments. But of course, somebody may just prove me wrong.

Comment: Fine, I do it myself * Thanos voice *. I started doing some research into elisp and org-mode's Latex expoerter and found about filters. Could I do some filter for headings that search for specifics :label: and place, at the begging of the heading, \begin{label}? Will the filter be applied before or after the addition of \section? And how could I place the \end{label}?

Comment: Filters are meant for minor modification of the output: they are not meant for restructuring the output. IIRC, they are invoked after the original output has been completely produced, IOW you have a string and you can modify it at will. But note that restructuring will need to *understand* the structure of that string, i.e. you will need to parse it; a minor change can be done with a replace-string and a regex and does not need to parse the string.

Comment: You *can* write your own exporter - look at `ox-latex.el` for the current exporter and use it as a template, but change its actions. It's not going to be easy, but I think it's the easiest way to get where you want to go.

Comment: It seems like the real problem is that once you start the definition headline, you can't end it short of creating a higher level headline. Blocks are delimited but headlines are strictly hierarchical.